# How to pass an image to Instagram from an Android app since Android 7+ / Nougart

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, instagram, android-7.0-nougat

I used to use the following code to send a photo from my App to Instagram...

```
this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Copy ready for Instagram App", true));

    var bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data

    /// You must first save your file in PNG or JPEG (preferred) format and use the filename extension ".ig"
    /// Using the iOS Document Interaction APIs you can trigger the photo to be opened by Instagram. 
    /// The Identifier for our Document Interaction UTI is com.instagram.photo, 
    /// and it conforms to the public/jpeg and public/png UTIs. 
    ///  Alternatively, if you want to show only Instagram in the application list 
    /// (instead of Instagram plus any other public/jpeg-conforming apps) you can specify the 
    /// extension class igo, which is of type com.instagram.exclusivegram.
    //Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string localFilename = "temp.jpg"; // <-- NOTE IGO to exclusively show instagram
    string localPath = Path.Combine(ExternalStorageDirectory, localFilename);

    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage
    this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Copy ready for Instagram App", false));

    /// See the Apple documentation articles: Previewing and Opening Files and the 
    /// UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference for more information.
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {

        this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Launching Instagram App", true));
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        shareIntent.SetType("image/*");

        Java.IO.File media = new Java.IO.File(ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + localFilename);
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(media);

        shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri); // set uri
        shareIntent.SetPackage("com.instagram.android");
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(shareIntent);
        this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Launching Instagram App", false));

        this.Publish(new InstagramServiceEvent(message, true));
    });
```

But now if I target Android 7+ I receive the following error

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <405ad2ab226e4e74ba67db96baf95129>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <405ad2ab226e4e74ba67db96baf95129>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Content.ContextWrapper.StartActivity (Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x00031] in <476f28c60f03479ab89477af687cdc1a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at nativeapp.Droid.InstagramService+<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<SendToInstagram>b__1 () [0x0007a] in /Users/rob/Documents/GitHub/social-scheduler/nativeapp/Droid/Services/InstagramService.cs:122 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <476f28c60f03479ab89477af687cdc1a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <476f28c60f03479ab89477af687cdc1a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.17(intptr,intptr)
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed Android.OS.FileUriExposedException stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1960)
[MonoDroid]     at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
[MonoDroid]     at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:942)
[MonoDroid]     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9850)
[MonoDroid]     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9835)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1610)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
[MonoDroid]     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
[MonoDroid]
```

I've seen some references to using a file handler FileProvider (see [ProAndroidDev article](https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-files-though-intents-are-you-ready-for-nougat-70f7e9294a0b)  ) but I don't quite understand how it works and whether it enables me to simply pass the image to Instagram.  All the domain stuff it mentions in the article left me very confused.

Is there a nicer way for me to simply pass the image to Instagram? In the future I would like to also consider video support too, so if that can be taken into account that'll be great.

For now I have set my target Android version to 6 so that the app continues to work, but I do want to set the target to something much more modern and this is my only stumbling point.

Comment: Yes, you need to implement a `FileProvider` in your Xamarin.Android application project

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover - I've now implemented it and it works 

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Leon Lu - I have now submitted my answer for your consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful links are

[Android Developer - Secure File Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)

[Pro Android Dev.com - blog](https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-files-though-intents-are-you-ready-for-nougat-70f7e9294a0b)

The hardest part was understand exactly where to put everything, so I've included the full context to make things easier for someone else.

First the Android Manifest, which includes App Center Push stuff, but I've clearly shown the File Sharing section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.devology.socialscheduler" android:versionName="1.11.3" android:versionCode="36" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
        <application android:label="Social Scheduler App" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

            <!-- App Center PUSH -->
            <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
            <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

            <!-- File Sharing -->
            <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.devology.socialscheduler.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
            </provider>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The File Provider points to a resource called @xml/file_provider_paths and it's important to put this in the right place...

[image: Where to put file_provider_paths]

And this is the contents of file_provider_paths.xml

```
<!-- e.g. content://com.devology.socialscheduler.fileprovider/myimages/default_image.jpg -->
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

Then this is where I download the image from the internet into a temporary file, then I create a URL using the file provider to then pass it to the Android sharing sheet

```
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Downloading image from Social Scheduler", false));

        if (e.Error != null)
        {

            this.Publish(new InstagramServiceEvent(message, false));

            this.Publish(
                new ToasterEvent(
                "Oops - " + e.Error.Message));

        }
        else
        {

            this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Copy ready for Instagram App", true));

            var bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data

            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            AppStorageDirectory = context.FilesDir + Java.IO.File.Separator; //+"images";

            /// You must first save your file in PNG or JPEG (preferred) format and use the filename extension ".ig"
            /// Using the iOS Document Interaction APIs you can trigger the photo to be opened by Instagram. 
            /// The Identifier for our Document Interaction UTI is com.instagram.photo, 
            /// and it conforms to the public/jpeg and public/png UTIs. 
            ///  Alternatively, if you want to show only Instagram in the application list 
            /// (instead of Instagram plus any other public/jpeg-conforming apps) you can specify the 
            /// extension class igo, which is of type com.instagram.exclusivegram.
            //Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string localFilename = "temp.jpg"; // <-- NOTE IGO to exclusively show instagram
            string localPath = Path.Combine(AppStorageDirectory, localFilename);

            File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage
            this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Copy ready for Instagram App", false));

            /// See the Apple documentation articles: Previewing and Opening Files and the 
            /// UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference for more information.
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Launching Instagram App", true));
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
                shareIntent.SetType("image/*");

                Java.IO.File media = new Java.IO.File(AppStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + localFilename);

                var fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(
                MainActivity.CURRENT_ACTIVITY,
                "com.devology.socialscheduler.fileprovider",
                media);

                //Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(media);

                shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri); // set uri
                shareIntent.SetPackage("com.instagram.android");
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(shareIntent);
                this.Publish(new MaskMessageEvent("Launching Instagram App", false));

                this.Publish(new InstagramServiceEvent(message, true));
            });
        }
    };

    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(message.ImageUrl));
```

Note there's some old comments in there about using the file extension IGO - this used to ensure only Instagram was offered, but that seemed to stop working at some point.